# iron:router render multiple templates inside main yield

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to crate a page, where i keep the navigation and the footer template always on, and in the main yield, i load the data refering to the page i am accessing.

my problem is, in the routes.js file i used the following

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'mainLayout',
    //notFoundTemplate:"notFoundTemplate",
    //loadingTemplate:"loadingTemplate",
});

Router.route('/', function () {

    this.render('navigation', {to: 'navigation'});
    this.render('footer', {to: 'footer'});
    this.render('carousel');
    this.render('oper_areas');
    this.render('partners');
});
```

and my mainLayout template goes like this

```
<template name="mainLayout">

  <header>
    {{> yield 'navigation'}}
  </header>

    {{> yield }}


  <footer class="full-width">
    {{> yield 'footer'}}
  </footer>


</template>
```

so i am sending the navigation template to the navigation yield, the footer to the footer yield and this is working fine, and then i am trying to fill the {{> yield }} with the content of 'carousel', 'oper_areas' and 'partners', this will assemble all the information i need to create my main page, but only the last one is showing.

is there anyway i can put the 3 templates inside the same {{> yield }} at the same time?

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with IronRouter. You can create a container template and yield that.

Comment: You mean assemble the data tamplates in another template and then route it?

Comment: And then yield it in a route, yes.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try this and then i will get back here.

Comment: Hello, i came back here to say that @MasterAM is correct, it was not possible to do that with iron router.
I had to create a template and then yield that template in the index.html.